# Best practices for software configuration?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, configuration-management, ansible

I'm configuring my AWS EC2 instances with Ansible, but I don't know what's the best way of storing my app configuration.

Now I'm just sending a "app.properties" file to the server, using Ansible, but I'd like to remove that from my source control. Also, I'd like to store everything on environment variables, instead os files, to make it more secure.

Is there a good tool for that? Something simple, like a key-val configuration server, where all your servers will connect and get their own properties?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at cloud-init and AWS tags.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand enough about your configuraiton to answer your query about environment variables vs property files.
However in answer to second part there are at least 2 systems I know designed for this need:

[etcd](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/getting-started-with-etcd/)
and
[zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/)